# Simple two variable limit problem, find the limit, if exists, of $f(x,y)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{xy}) $:

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} x^2\sin(\frac{1}{xy}) $ if exists, and find $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}(\lim_{y\to 0} x^2\sin(\frac{1}{xy}) ), \displaystyle\lim_{y\to 0}(\lim_{x\to 0} x^2\sin(\frac{1}{xy}) )$ if they exist.

Hey everyone. I've tried using the squeeze theorem and found $0 \le |x^2\sin(\frac{1}{xy})| \le |x^2|\cdot 1 \xrightarrow{x\to0} 0 $ and so the "double" limit exists and equals zero.
Now, I know $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(\frac{1}{ax})$ diverges, so both $lim_{y\to 0}(\lim_{x\to 0} x^2\sin(\frac{1}{xy}) )$  and $lim_{x\to 0}(\lim_{y\to 0} x^2\sin(\frac{1}{xy}) )$ do not exist(?)

I don't think I understand multi-variable limits, I would love your help on this basic one so I can understand better. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes the solution by squeeze theorem is correct! What are your other doubts?

Comment: You are right that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \sin(\frac{1}{xy})$ doesn't exist (I wouldn't use the term diverges) but the term $x^2$ suffices to make the whole limit exists and it is equal to $0$.

Comment: Well done! You are welcome, Bye!

Comment: @gimusi That must mean one of us is wrong, because you claim that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} x^2\sin(\frac{1}{xy})$ exists and I claim it doesn't. Shall we consult the gods?

Comment: @ThePhenotype ops I didn't noticed that, let me check! :)

Comment: The question is, whether only if both the second and the third limit exist, and they are both different- then we can conclude the first one does not exist.

Comment: @NoyPerel What you are saying is almost correct. The first one might also not exist if we have that one of the two other limits doesn't exist.

Comment: @ThePhenotype Thank you, that's a confusing topic- I should read about this more and see different examples

Comment: @NoyPerel You can find many example here on MSE, here for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2647468/505767, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2624273/505767, etc

Comment: @NoyPerel Please give the accept gimusi's answer, without him I would have given you fake mathematics. Everything I wrote in my answer (even though it has more words) is based on what he said to me.

Comment: Thank you both, I am much more enlightened now! :) I will check out those posts

Comment: @NoyPerel You are free to accept the answer you prefer, also after editing, it is a community and it doesn't mind wheter or not I gave some hint for other answer. Please feel free to choose the answer that you prefer!

Comment: @ThePhenotype Thank for your kindness, but I think that Noy must be free to choose the answer that him/her prefer! No problem for me, It's fine to help one each other and solve the OP in the best way for the asker!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need simply to note that

$$0\le \left|x^2\sin(\frac{1}{xy})\right|\le x^2\to 0$$

then conclude by squeeze theorem.

Comment: I don't want to be *that guy*, but you only repeated what OP said and then added "conclude"... Please don't turn into Dr. Graubner (no offense to him, but I seem him notoriously often among the Low Quality Posts).

Comment: @ThePhenotype I've just indicated the plane way to solve this kind of limit, then I've added some comment to the other doubts formulated by the asker. The argument used also by you seems very confusing to me and not correct, What is your thought about that and about the comment I've added under your answer?

Answer (score 3):

$0 \le |x^2\sin(\frac{1}{xy})| \le |x^2| \xrightarrow{x\to0} 0$ means indeed that for any trajectory of $(x,y)$ going to $(0,0)$ we have that $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{xy})$ approaches $0$.

---

Note that just by taking any $y\neq 0$ fixed we cannot just conclude that it would not approach $0$, since eventually you also want $y$ to approach $0$. Indeed we can see that $y\neq 0$ fixed is a trajectory that does not intersect or approach $(0,0)$.

Comment: I'm not sure about your argument, you fix $x\neq 0$ but recall that $x\to 0$. To show that limit doesn't exist we shold find two different trajectories with $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ with different limits. By squeeze theorem it seem really clear that the limit is equal to $0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @gimusi I think you do have a point. I should actually try to find a trajectory with a non-convergent limit, but I can't seem to find one...

Comment: $\sin \frac{1}{xy}$ is bounded between $[-1,1]$ therefore $\lim_{x \to 0} x^{2}\sin \frac{1}{xy} = 0$.

Comment: @ThePhenotype Indeed squeeze theorem seems indicate that such trajectories don't exist at all.

Comment: @gimusi Alright, I'm convinced! Deleting my post in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: @NoyPerel gimusi is right about this one. The trajectory I gave is a line that doesn't actually go to $(0,0)$.

Comment: @ThePhenotype That's ok, thank you still :)

Comment: @ThePhenotype You are welcome! I really appreciate your sense of  humor and frankness! ;)

Comment: @ThePhenotype You can always revise the answer!

Comment: @gimusi Thanks haha. Well okay, I will revise it. Also thanks for enlightening me :)

Comment: @ThePhenotype You are very welcome! I hope you will be hearty with me when the next time I will be not completely correct! Bye :)

Answer (score 2):

So the moral of this question is that, one might think that if the double limit exists, then it entails the existence of iterated limits, this question gives a counterexample, but what is true is that,

> Given that $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(a,b)}f(x,y)=L$ exists and that for each $x\in B_{\delta}(a)-\{a\}$, $\lim_{y\rightarrow b}f(x,y)=M_{x}$ exists, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}M_{x}=L$, in other words, $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\lim_{y\rightarrow b}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(a,b)}f(x,y)$.

The assumption that for a deleted neigborhood of $a$ that the existence of $\lim_{y\rightarrow b}f(x,y)$ cannot be relaxed.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this!